How to understand the use of "used to"?
I have talked about these two verbs "used to" and "might" with my tutor. She told me that we can use them when we want to show that some activity was done many times in the past. She also told me to remember that we don't use those two verbs with definite time expressions. She told me that it isn"t grammatically wrong but just unidiomatic. I forgot to ask one more question so I'm gonna ask you.

In the past, I used to drive a truck for 7 years in that firm

In the past, I might drive a truck  for 7 years in that firm


As I understand my examples aren't natural, but what if  I said something like that by mistake ( I mean what if I add a definite time expression to those two verbs). Would you understand that 1 and 2 mean that during a single seven year period I sometimes did something or that I did something here driving a truck many times in the past and each attempt took seven years?

"in the past" is not necessary (as used to is always used with the past) and is too general. Typical expressions would be more specific.  When I was a child.   When I lived in London.  When I was a student at that school.

The second is not grammatical because of "for seven years".  Compare: "When I worked at that firm, I might not see my wife for weeks at a time because I was working the night shift seven days a week on a special  hush-hush project. Such projects were not unusual."

There are many, many mistakes that don't keep someone from understanding your meaning. That said, #2 might cause some confusion. I'm curious what your tutor said about "might"; it's not too common, especially when talking about things that definitely happened.

@AndyBonner I could make no sense of #2.

@TimR true; I guess I guessed the meaning only because I just read #1. In a real conversation, context might help, but if it were said out of the blue I would have to guess at several possible meetings, and would be most likely to land on "in the past, I admired that firm so much that I might have been willing to drive a truck for them for 7 years."

Usage examples: 1) I used to drive a truck for that firm. 2) In the past, I might drive a truck for 7 hours without a break.

Constructions like used to [bare verb] (e.g.used to go, used to sing) refer to actions in the past that happened  regularly or to a situation that was ongoing, such as a job.

When I was a kid, we used to go to the beach every summer.
When I was in college, the entire student body used to pack the campus theater on Friday night to watch a movie together on the big screen.
She used to be a ballerina but suffered an injury to her leg and could no longer dance.

When might is used to refer to past actions, it refers to actions that were usual yet unusual, not unusual yet in some way unusual, somewhat out of the ordinary but not completely so, something which happened more often than occasionally:

When I was an intern at that company, I would go for weeks with almost nothing to do and then a project would come along where I might have to work overtime for a month straight.
When we were kids, we didn't have video games. After dinner, and after our homework was done, we used to go outdoors at dusk and play hide-and-seek or flashlight tag when it got dark. Or we might throw stones up at bats to make them think it was an insect.

And so we could rewrite the sentence about watching movies in college:

When I was in college, the entire student body might pack the campus theater on a Friday night to watch a movie together on the big screen.

If it didn't happen every Friday night, but happened often enough to be considered a fairly regular thing, you could use might instead of used to.  It was not unusual for us and yet in some sense it was unusual.

+1 Excellent description of the difference with very practical examples.

The short answer to your specific question is that context will often lead a listener to correctly understand your meaning. For example, consider your first sentence:

In the past, I used to drive a truck for 7 years in that firm.

What you're really asking is, What does for seven years refer to? Now it's theoretically possible that you are describing a job where you had shifts requiring you to drive continuously for seven years. But any good listener will understand immediately the common sense meaning: You worked for the company for seven years, and during that time you regularly drove trucks.
Having said that, my advice is that if you have any doubts about your meaning, try to rewrite or rethink the whole sentence. In both writing and speaking, one good way to do that is to simplify and shorten your language units. For example:

I worked in that firm for seven years. During that time, I used to drive trucks.
I worked in that firm for seven years. My main job was in the store room, but I might drive trucks as well if the main driver was on leave.

Note that in this case used to implies regular activity, whereas might implies occasional and less frequent activity.

Shouldn't that be 'but I might have driven trucks'? I think the tense of 'might drive' does still need to agree with 'was', even though that's ambiguous (because it implies the speaker is unsure).

No. Might in that sentence does not imply doubt. It implies occasional activity. Read TimR's excellent answer on this point. As for the tense, drive is correct. I used to drive. (regular driving). I might drive. (Occasional driving as required). It's the same structure.

In my correction to your answer, I suggested a form ('might have driven') that was ambiguous and would more normally imply doubt.
I'm quite confident that you're wrong - I'd be very grateful if you could add a reference or an in-the-wild example of using might in the past tense in this way.

I'm comfortable that my example is correct. I'm happy to update my answer with a clearer example if you need it. But first, I repeat: Have you read TimR's answer which deals with exactly this issue?

Maybe it will help you to look at this another way. Might certainly implies doubt, but what doubt? The doubt is not that I drove at all. It's doubt about the particular days and times when I drove. If I change the tense to might have driven, it will change the meaning. It will leave open the possibility that I never drove. (It's never about the rules, it's about the meaning that we want to communicate.)
